# Why does my ifdigit glitch

Tags: c

Sometimes when I enter no numbers at all in the **fgets()** my isdigit condition is still met. Does not happen all the time but rarely. Why does it do this? here's the code.

```
void calculate(){

    char item_name[20];
    int i;

    printf("\nEnter Your Product:");
    fgets(item_name, 20, stdin);

    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
        if(isdigit(item_name[i])){
            Errorlevel("Input Has a Number");
        }
    }

    internet(item_name);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens if you as input enter *less* than 19 characters? What is the value of the uninitialized elements of `item_name`? Isn't there a nice way to [get the length of a string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out before, item_name will contain junk on the part *not touched by fgets()*. So ok for

> fgets(item_name, 20, stdin);

then check for errors (result from fgets). After that, your cycle:

> for(i=0; i<20; i++){

checks *always* 20 characters, but fgets() could have read less. fgets() always terminates the buffer with a NUL (and, may be, an LF before it). You can avoid to check the length by putting a controlled break in your cycle. Maybe an empty string is ok for you, maybe not, but this cycle:

```
for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
  if ( item_name[i] == 0 ) break;  // NUL - always present
  if ( item_name[i] == 10) break;  // LF - do you want to manage it?

  if (isdigit(item_name[i])) {
    Errorlevel("Input Has a Number");
  }
}
```

I think that, probably, you don't want LF in the string; if so, you can overwrite it with a NUL.

Comment: Hmm ok so what does LF mean and also why the number 10

Comment: @Syntax LF is the line end (when you press Enter to input data, fgets() copies that "key" too). The number 10 is the ascii code of LF, one way to check for it (another way is '\n').

Comment: Ok now I get it. Also seems to have worked. Program has not messed up since I implanted your code thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing your `item_name` array and possibly just encountering junk that might be stored there, especially as you are not checking the length of the stored string and your `for` loop is iterating over the entire array length.